# Close 'Show Applications' screen via click

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, dock

After clicking *Show Applications* in the dock, on the occasion I don't click an app, I'd like to click anywhere in the window to close it. Currently I have to mouse down and click the *Show Application* icon again for the window to close. Is this possible?

- Ubuntu 18.04.1
- Dash-to-Dock v64

[image: Ubuntu Show Applications Screenshot with dash to dock]

Comment: You can press Escape Key too, it's the easiest means to close Show Applications.

Comment: Or better press <Super> or click '*Activities*' at the top-left corner to close the Show Applications screen. Also just to confirm, did you manually install the Dash-to-Dock extension. The one that is shipped with Ubuntu 18.04 by default is not exactly Dash-to-Dock, but a fork of it.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! Currently I have a bottom left hot corner setup for open/close apps and I knew about Activities (setup as a hot corner as well.) Also, yes, I installed via Gnome Shell Extensions site. Either way, "click-to-close" apps window would be the quickest and a nice feature to have, yes?

Comment: Super works. Escape goes to Activities and escape once more closes it. On second thought, maybe super is the quickest; and one less click.

Comment: The fact that you have to hit Escape twice to get out is not great UX.  Haven't seen anything else do it that way.  It's hard to remember when moving around the computer quickly that when you get to Show Applications, you have to switch your escaping shortcut.  Would be great if there was a way to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [GNOME shell extension](https://askubuntu.com/q/75530/480481) which does the job to some extent: **[Hide Overview When Click Overview](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1025/hide-overview-when-click-overview/)**.

> A Click on an empty space in the overview hide the overview. If you clicked at workspacesPage it minimizes all windows on the current workspace and show desktop. Other pages just hide overview.

But I prefer pressing <kbd>Super</kbd> to close the '*Show Applications*' screen quickly.

Comment: Nice! Seems to be working (although some recent comments suggest otherwise.) And it's nice to have it working in Activities as well.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can create a launcher for simulating <kbd>Escape</kbd> key.

For simulating you need `xdotool` to be installed.

```
sudo apt install xdotool
```

Create a `ESC.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications/`

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/ESC.desktop
```

Paste the below content in it.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Name=ESC
Exec=xdotool key Escape
Name[en_IN]=ESC
```

Save & Close.

Run

```
chmod +x ~/.local/share/applications/ESC.desktop
```

to make the file executable.

Now when you click show all apps icon, you will have "ESC" entry.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing! This isn't what I'm looking for though, it may be a route others prefer for themselves. Plus, it's good to know about just in general.